# Tricky logic -SQL,Teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata

Here is a tricky scenario am trying to solve.
`Table A1`: has 4 columns. And this table keeps updating once in 2 days.

```
id    name  fav_color  date
2051  joe   white      07/21
2052  John  green      07/21
```

After 2 days records are updated and `table A1` looks like this.

```
id    name  fav_color  date
2051  joe   blue       07/23
2052  Rick  green      07/23
```

`Table A2`: this is a history table that captures all the changes being done to `table A1`.

```
id    updated_column   update_dt  old_value  new_value
2051  fav_color        07/23      white      blue
2052  Name             07/23      John       Rick
```

Now business wants to see a monthly snapshot of table A1 by the end of the month.
basically I want a monthly snapshot like this.

```
id    name  fav_color  date
2051  joe   white      07/21
2051  joe   blue       07/23
2052  John  green      07/21
2052  Rick  green      07/23
```

Please tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: Are these example columns, or is this real?

Comment: How many records do you expect in table A1 and A2?

Comment: Are you also storing the old `date` value in the history column? Because if you don't there is no way to know that the `old_value` was valid on that specific date and I don't see a way to get the output you want

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You only get this problem with the very first value the records had. The date of those is not known. We probably have to ignore the first values ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,name,fav_color,date
FROM tableA1

UNION ALL

SELECT tableA2.id,
       CASE WHEN tableA2.updatedColumn ='name' 
            THEN tableA2.oldValue
            ELSE tableA1.name END,
       CASE WHEN tableA2.updatedColumn ='fav_color' 
            THEN tableA2.oldValue
            ELSE tableA1.fav_color END,
       tableA2.update_dt
FROM tableA2
INNER JOIN tableA1 ON tableA2.id=tableA1.id
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. The else in both case statements returns the current value, but it should show the unchanged value at that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

A very primitive, slow and probably incomplete way, which should more or less return what you need:

```
SELECT
  dates.id,
  dates.date,
  (SELECT TOP (1) name.new_value 
   FROM A2 name 
   WHERE name.id = dates.id and name.date <= dates.date and name.updated_column = 'name') as name,
  (SELECT TOP (1) favcol.new_value 
   FROM A2 favcol 
   WHERE favcol.id = dates.id and favcol.date <= dates.date and favcol.updated_column = 'fav_color') as fav_color
FROM A2 dates
```

order by dates.id, dates.date

The very first values are ignored. It's probably a point to start from.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of dependencies, but something like this might do it.

```
select 
 name.id
, name.name 
, color.fav_color 
, color.update_dt
from 
(select 
 id
,update_dt
,new_value
from a2
where update_column = 'fav_color') color
join 
(select
 id
,update_dt
,new_value
from a2
where update_column = 'name') name
on color.id = name.id and color.update_dt = name.update_dt
order by color.update_dt, name.id
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your Teradata release?

In TD14.10 there's LAST_VALUE, which can be used to replace NULLs with the previous value:

```
SELECT
   id,
   LAST_VALUE(name IGNORE NULLS) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY id 
         ORDER BY datecol DESC) AS name,
   LAST_VALUE(fav_color IGNORE NULLS) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY id 
         ORDER BY datecol DESC) AS fav_color,
   MAX(datecol) -- date of change, NULL for the first version
   OVER (PARTITION BY id 
         ORDER BY datecol DESC
         ROWS BETWEEN  1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS detail
FROM
 (
   SELECT id, NAME, fav_color, DATE '9999-12-31' AS datecol -- current version
   FROM a1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT -- previous versions
      id,
      MAX(CASE WHEN updated_column = 'name' THEN old_value END) AS name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN updated_column = 'fav_color' THEN old_value END) AS fav_color,
      update_dt
   FROM a2
   GROUP BY id, update_dt
 ) AS dt
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this one.**

`select * from 
(
  select id,name,fav_color,date1 
  from Table1
  union all
  select t2.id,
  Case t2.updated_column 
     when 'Name' then t2.new_value 
     else t1.name End as name,
  Case t2.updated_column 
     when 'fav_color' then t2.new_value 
     else t1.fav_color End as fav_color,
  t2.update_dt as date1 
  from Table2 t2
  Inner Join Table1 t1
  on t1.id = t2.id
)A  order by 1 Asc`